# How to setMargins in LinearLayout in Java?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use the setMargins method using ViewGroup but I keep getting the error that `setMargins is not defined` .This is my code:

```
LinearLayout content = new LinearLayout(activity);
            LayoutParams params = content.getLayoutParams();
            params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 40);
            content.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use LayoutParams to set your button margins:

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
yourbutton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Depending on what layout you're using you should use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams or LinearLayout.LayoutParams.

And to convert your dp measure to pixel, try this:

```
Resources r = mContext.getResources();
int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
        yourdpmeasure, 
        r.getDisplayMetrics()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to setMargins depend on any view (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc.)

Pass the params in integer format

```
public static void setMargins(View view, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    if (view.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        p.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
        view.requestLayout();
    }
}
```